# Parsed JSON Data to be used in Another CLass?

Tags: android, json, class, parsing

I am able to parse JSON Data and set Name in the Navigation Drawer Header.I have parsed data on the Home Activity after login java class(i.e home class).I have fragments on Navigation drawer and when i click the profile fragment,it should populate the name,address from the JSON.How can the parsed JSON Data in One class be used on the Other class.

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    LinearLayout calendar, classSchedule, progressReport, profile, fee, dshboard, setting, logout, attendance;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/students/";
    ImageView studentprofileimage;
    TextView profilename, sprofilename;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        studentprofileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);//initilise student name
        profilename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profilename);// student profile name
        sprofilename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.student_profilename);


        dshboard = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_layout);
        calendar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calender_layout);
        fee = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_fee);
        classSchedule = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_schedule);
        progressReport = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_report);
        profile = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
        setting = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainsetting);
        logout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlogout);
        attendance = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_attendance);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        classSchedule.setOnClickListener(this);
        fee.setOnClickListener(this);
        dshboard.setOnClickListener(this);
        progressReport.setOnClickListener(this);
        profile.setOnClickListener(this);
        setting.setOnClickListener(this);
        logout.setOnClickListener(this);
        attendance.setOnClickListener(this);
        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard());
        tx.commit();

        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Home.this);
        session.checkLogin();
        String master_id = session.getMasterId();
        Log.d("TAG", "master_id:" + master_id);
        makeJsonObjectRequest(Integer.parseInt(master_id));
        Log.d("TAG", "master_id:" + master_id);
        //master_id = session.clear();


    }

    StudentInformation studentInformation;

    public void makeJsonObjectRequest(int stud_id) {
        String URL = Navigation_URL + stud_id;
        Log.d("TAG", "URL:" + URL);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            studentInformation = new StudentInformation();
                            studentInformation.Name = jsonObject.getString("NAME");
                            profilename.setText(studentInformation.Name);
                            //       sprofilename.setText(studentInformation.Name);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();


        if (id == R.id.dashboard_layout) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else if (id == R.id.calender_layout) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CalenderFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.view_fee) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Fee())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else if (id == R.id.class_schedule) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentClassSchedule())
                    .commit();


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.progress_report) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProgressFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.class_attendance) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new AttendanceStudentFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.view_profile) {

            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            bundle1.putSerializable("student_obj", studentInformation);


            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProfileFragment())
                    .commit();
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.mainsetting) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new SettingFragment())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (id == R.id.mainlogout) {

            SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Home.this);
            session.clear();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }


    }


}
```

**StudentInformation.java**

```
   public class StudentInformation implements Serializable {


    String PhoneNumber;
    String DOB;
    String ClassName;
    String Gender;
    public String Image;

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public Integer studentId;

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }

    public String Name;


    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }


    public void setDOB(String DOB) {
        this.DOB = DOB;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return ClassName;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        ClassName = className;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return PhoneNumber;

    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;

    }


    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender = gender;
    }


}
```

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
  public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView profilename; // i want to set name on this textView


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        profilename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profilename);
        //  StudentInformation studentInformation = null;
        // studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("");
        // profilename.setText(studentInformation.getName());


        if(this.getArguments().getSerializable("student_obj")!=null)
        {
            Serializable student_obj_serializable = getArguments().getSerializable("student_obj");
            StudentInformation student_obj=(StudentInformation)student_obj_serializable;

            //set all value here
            profilename.setText(student_obj.getName());
        }

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do s.th.
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

i am not able to parsed data to be used on Another class?

Comment: If you'r directy going to profile fragment on click then simply pass data with bundle using `setArguments(bundle)` for fragment. You can also store data in shared preference and access it in your desired class.

Comment: or try using a global variable

Comment: @Piyush can you provide some code snippet

Comment: Code snippet is available if you dig a google with _How to pass data to fragment from activity_. It will returns the results.

Comment: @NIlabja global variable for which one??

Comment: @PIyush sure piyush i will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save All data in model class and pass that model class object to fragment using setArguments(bundle)

Model Class:

```
    public class StudentInformation  implements Serializable {


        private String PhoneNumber;
        private String DOB;
        private String ClassName;
        private String Gender;
        private String Image;


        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return PhoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getDOB() {
            return DOB;
        }

        public void setDOB(String DOB) {
            this.DOB = DOB;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return ClassName;
        }

        public void setClassName(String className) {
            ClassName = className;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return Gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            Gender = gender;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return Image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            Image = image;
        }
    }
```

makeJsonObjectRequest:

```
    //declare global

    StudentInformation studentInformation ;

    public void makeJsonObjectRequest(int stud_id) {
    String URL = Navigation_URL + stud_id;
    Log.d("TAG", "URL:" + URL);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        studentInformation = new StudentInformation();
                       // studentInformation.Name = jsonObject.getString("NAME");

                         studentInformation.setName(jsonObject.getString("NAME"));

                        profilename.setText(studentInformation.getName());
                        //       sprofilename.setText(studentInformation.Name);

                        //parse all data here and set all info to studentInformation



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

  }
```

on profile button click:

```
if (id == R.id.view_profile) {

        Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putSerializable("student_obj", studentInformation);

        Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle1);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

          DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
```

ProfileFragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    profilename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profilename);
    //  StudentInformation studentInformation = null;
    // studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("");
    // profilename.setText(studentInformation.getName());

    if(this.getArguments().getSerializable("student_obj")!=null)
    {
        Serializable student_obj_serializable = getArguments().getSerializable("student_obj");
       StudentInformation student_obj=(StudentInformation)student_obj_serializable;

       //set all value here
       profilename.setText(student_obj.getName());
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: at home class,As i have parsed only name

Comment: i have got error
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: you  implements your model class Serializable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137513/discussion-between-user2025187-and-seon).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send Json data from one activity to another then make a class and extends it to serializable and create all parameter variable in the class.
Then create the object of the class and store all Json data in object and if you have multiple such objects to send then make array of type class you created and send it through Intent.

Comment: can't i set it on textView directly by creating object of the class on which the data is parsed

Comment: yes you can. You were doing it right. You can send that class object directly to another activity using Intent

Answer (score 0):

yes you can store data into model and get but any manipulation on model you will get wrong data so store it in sql lite at the time of main activity then get data from navigation drawer

Comment: cant i create the object of the home class, on fragment and use the function which has data, and set it directly

Comment: you can store it on after parsing in makeJsonObjectRequest  methods at the time of geting data

Comment: i have use this
 //  StudentInformation studentInformation = null;
        // studentInformation = (StudentInformation) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("");
        // profilename.setText(studentInformation.getName());
but its showing error

Comment: if it is showing null pointer so in this line means you have problem in parshing debug and check you had succefully parse or not